# Как открыть и отсортировать txt file c#

Tags: c#

Как реализовать с помощью c#, сортировкутекста из txt файла, а именно, открыть файл txt я знаю как, но как отсортировать слова, которые найду в нем, к примеру:

Мне нужно, открыть файл mail.txt и отсортировать каждую строку, к примеру, строку ivanov@email.com нужно перенести в текстовый документ @email.com.txt.

```
string path_mail;
int count2 = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path2).Length;
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog2 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog2.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt";
            openFileDialog2.FilterIndex = 2;
            openFileDialog2.RestoreDirectory = true;
            if (openFileDialog2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
            path_mail = openFileDialog2.FileName;    
                for (int i = 0; i <count2; i++)
                {
               // Тут действие по сортировке
            }
        }
```

Comment: Предоставьте Ваши попытки или Ваш код который Вы уже выполнили. С колена Вам код писать никто не отважиться. Было бы неплохо ещё скриншот с содержимым файла.

Comment: @SeeSharp - _неплохо бы ещё скриншот с содержимым файла_ - а как же: "**Никогда, прошу Вас, не используйте фотографию, в качестве кода**"?

Comment: Хм приятно слышать но всё же. Он привел примеры из **файла** с которым мне нужно работать. И я честно говоря немогу представить как я буду без этого файла работать с этим же файлом. Можно конечно и ссылку на скачку но это слишком))

Comment: @SeeSharp я бы с радостью кинул был свои наработки, но не могу реализовать сам. Все форумы облазил уже.

Comment: Правьте вопрос,пожалуйста, и опишите Вашу задачу по подробнее.

Comment: @SeeSharp обновил вопрос.

Comment: Отлично. Пишу ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Что мы сделали?

---

Я выучил класс **Regex** что и Вам советую. Долго бы провозился без него. Знаю можно короче но я пытался. Здесь мы объявили метод который получает конец строки с **email** в формате `@somemail.com` что бы создать txt файл или вставить в него значение полной ссылки. Прошлись циклом [**foreach**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/uk-ua/library/ttw7t8t6(v=vs.120).aspx) по массиву строк из файла-не отсортированного что бы внести данные в файл и узнать в какой его добавлять. Далее есть комментарии я думаю там всё понятно.

---

Удачи. **SeeSharp**

**Вот код:**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string Rpattern = @"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*";
        Regex regex = new Regex(Rpattern);
        var pathFile = @"D:\ВЛАД\test.txt";//Путь к файлу из которого нужно сортировать значения
        string[] tosort = File.ReadAllLines(pathFile);//массив из строк которые получили из файла
        foreach (string fromFile in tosort)
        {

                if (regex.Match(fromFile).Success)
                {
                        File.AppendAllText($@"D:\\ВЛАД\Folder\{GetEndType(fromFile)}.txt", fromFile);//если строка из файла оканчаеться на один из фильтров
                        //Мы записываем его текст в файл с названием его конца (да сложно) а если его нету то создадим но всеравно закинем туда этот текст
                }

        }
    }
    static string GetEndType(string txt)
    {
        string Rpattern2 = @"@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$";
        Regex regex = new Regex(Rpattern2);
        if (!regex.Match(txt).Success)
            return txt;
        else
            return GetEndType(txt.Remove(0, 1));
    }
```

Comment: А можно реализовать как-то без массива? Чтобы почтовые домены знал какие, так как доменов таких более тысяча и добавлять каждый в массив это долго и не оптимально.

Comment: да можно сейчас попробую реализовать.

Comment: Cпасибо, выручил.

Comment: Чтобы избежать чтение и запись всех строк в массив, используйте метод `File.ReadLines`: он возвращает строки файла по мере перечисления (ленивые вычисления). Тем самым память не будет нагружаться

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант:

```
File.ReadAllLines("mails.txt")
    .Select(x => x.Split('@'))
    .Select(x => new {Domain = x[1], Mail = x[0]})
    .GroupBy(x => x.Domain)
    .ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.Select(x => $"{x.Mail}@{d.Key}"))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(f => File.AppendAllLines($"@{f.Key}.txt", f.Value));
```

- `File.ReadAllLines("mails.txt")` - читаем исходный файл построчно и заносим в массив.
- `.Select(x => x.Split('@'))` - разбиваем каждую строку на две части по `@`.
- `.Select(x => new {Domain = x[1], Mail = x[0]})` - для удобства создаем анонимный тип (можно и без него обойтись по сути..).
- `.GroupBy(x => x.Domain)` - группируем все по домену (`@domain.net`).
- `.ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.Select(x => $"{x.Mail}@{d.Key}"))` - формируем словарь, где Key будет содержать домен, а Value, массив собранных обратно строк.
- `.ToList()` - чисто что бы не писать цикл, а использовать его удобный Linq вариант `.ForEach()` (можно без этого, тогда придется пройтись циклом отдельно).
- `.ForEach(f => File.AppendAllLines($"@{f.Key}.txt", f.Value))` - ну и проходим по всем данным, записывая все по своим файлам (формат файла: `@domain.txt`).

Также тут можно после чтения файла добавить что то вроде `.Where(x=>x.Contains('@'))`, тогда отсечем все строчки, которые не содержать `@`, иначе будем падать!

Comment: Спасибо большое, за помощь

Comment: Я с тобой не дружбу. Ушёл учить linq

Comment: @SeeSharp на твоей галочкa стоит :D